# Unity 3D - Problems with Mad Catz R.A.T. Pro X extra buttons

Tags: unity-game-engine, joystick

A few Days ago my loved PC Mouse, a Razer Death Adder, died because of a rage attack of my boyfriend. So I decided to get a new one from Mad Catz, because why not trying ... A few days later I got her, a very nice Mad Catz R.A.T. PRO X.

I'm working with Unity 3D in the Version 4.0.0.0f. You may ask yourself why I'm not using the newest version? Answer is simple, I'm not allowed to, my University says all projects have to be done in the Version 4.0.0.0f.

Enough from the introduction... While testing a game I made, I pressed the DPI-Button on the R.A.T. and my character starts to constantly moving forward. It only stops if I leave the Screen and use for example my browser or another program or I restart unity completely.

I wrote a small script to show me what Buttons are pressed while I pressed the DPI-Button. It turns out that the following BUttons are Pressed if I press the DPI-Button:

- JoystickButton6
- Joystick1Button6

So I had a look in the Mad Catz Software and tried do define a custom Profile where the DPI-Button is simply a Shiftkey, the Software looks good but it had the same result in the game.

Is there any Unity 3D Developer with a Mad Catz R.A.T. PRO X with the same problem?

Comment: Found the Solution, I Deactivated the Driver for the internal Joystick and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Solution is to disable the Controller Driver of the Mouse.
It can be achieved by disabeling the driver in the computer management!